# Javascript:Build xml format

Tags: javascript

I need to build a xml as 
XML:

```
<Root>
 <Item1 absord="aa">
     <XItem n="a" v="b"/>
     <XItem n="a" v="b"/>
     <XItem n="a" v="b"/>
 </Item1>
  <Item1 absord="bb">
     <XItem n="a" v="b"/>
     <XItem n="a" v="b"/>
     <XItem n="a" v="b"/>
  </Item1>
</Root>
```

I`ve written a js function as below:

```
  function BuildChildXml(s, name,n)
    {
        var xj=OrchGenericObj.GetXMLObj("<R15></R15>");
        var INode1 = xj.createElement("Item1");
            INode1.setAttribute("Absord", n)
        var INode = xmlnewObj.createElement("XItem");
        INode.setAttribute("Name", name);
        INode.setAttribute("Urlpath",s);                    
        xj.documentElement.appendChild(INode);
        INode1.appendChild(xj)
    }
```

Output:

```
<Root>
 <Item1 absord="aa"/>
     <XItem n="a" v="b"/> 
  <Item1 absord="bb"/>
     <XItem n="a" v="b"/>
</Root>
```

But i`m not getting the required output.
Please correct the function.

Comment: What are errors you have got?

Comment: I have not got any,but the output is not as it has to be.

Comment: Could you edit your question and paste the output that you have got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating XItem node one time only so you are getting only one time.

your code should be like this

```
var xj=OrchGenericObj.GetXMLObj("<R15></R15>");
    var INode1 = xj.createElement("Item1");
       INode1.setAttribute("Absord", n)

    var INode = xmlnewObj.createElement("XItem");
       INode.setAttribute("Name", name);
       INode.setAttribute("Urlpath",s);                    
     INode1.documentElement.appendChild(INode);

    xj.appendChild(INode1);
}
```